# Can't access an ASP.NET application started in a docker container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, aspnetboilerplate

I started a docker container with an ASP.NET app inside. The logs say that  the application started successfully and is alive, but when I try to access the home page of the app I get the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE and the error page of the browser.
Here is my dockerfile:

```
  # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
  FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
  COPY /bin/Debug/net5.0/ App/
  WORKDIR /App
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TritaniumLocal.Web.Host.dll"]
```

Here is my docker build command: `docker build  -t "tritaniumlocal" .`
Here is my docker run command: `docker run -d -p 44311:44311 tritaniumlocal aspnetapp2`.
The app starts from Visual Studio on port 44311. I tried also without port remap, but nothing helped

UPD: Here is a part of a log which can  help:

`warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0] Unable to bind to http://localhost:44311 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Cannot assign requested address'. Hosting environment: Production Content root path: /App Now listening on: http://localhost:44311 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.`

Comment: what's inside your computer's `/bin/Debug/net5.0/` directory ?

Comment: I decided to build  the app outside the image and only copy the binaries of my app there

Comment: may be the binaries are in `$(pwd)/bin/Debug/net5.0/` ... not in `bin/Debug/net5.0/`

Comment: I added a dot before `/bin/Debug/net5.0/` and built and started a new container. Now I see the logs  in the console,which  signs that the app is alive but still can't access the app in the browser

Comment: Can you share the log ... I believe the app is running some other port than 44311

Comment: I've updated the description and added a log which can interrest you